# How to show a UIView for first lauch of an app?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I want to show a login view for the first login of an app. I find several answers in stackoverflow itself. But each of them produce a blackscreen with only status bar or displays my other home page..
Is there any way to solve this problem..

Explanation:

When somebody install the app and launch it for the first time,it should display a login page. From the next launch onwards the app should start from its home page.(Like we see in so many apps there will be a 'Getting started page' or 'How to play' view).

Thanx...

Comment: Explain in depth. What you're trying and what you get as a result.

Comment: Take a look at the "Single View Application" project template in Xcode.

Comment: No idea what you are talking about you can just create a UIViewController class to contain a UIView and then add in elements you want for your login page and also code please so i can see what i can do to help

Comment: @Ravisankarvm See Nikita's answer. I think it may help you...:)

Comment: @rckoenes : This is what i have done                             if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"]) 
    {
       self.window.rootViewController = self.fbv;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
    }
    else
    {
        self.window.rootViewController = self.goalsHome;
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do it this way:

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"]) {
 //first launch
 //show your login view
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"]
 }
 else
{
  // app already launched
}
```

Comment: +1 for the right one..:)

Comment: This is what i have done if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"]) { self.window.rootViewController = self.fbv; [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"]; } else { self.window.rootViewController = self.goalsHome; }

Answer (score 1):

What i understand from your question is when you run your app for the first time you want to load the Login View and after first time run you want to load some another view. In this case you can use the `NSUserDefaults` available in iOS.

When your application runs first time you can i.e. when you show the login view you can store some integer value in `NSUserDefaults`. And when you load the app next time you can check the value store in `NSUserDefaults` For e.g.

```
if(value == 0)
  // load Login View
else
  // load other view
```

Answer (score 0):

--First of  all import ur login page.h file in appdelegate file

after that

In appdelegate.m file

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

//Here create ur login page class's object like below code

  YourLoginPage *Login=[[YourLoginPage alloc]initWithNibName:@"YourLoginPage" bundle:nil];

self.window.rootViewController = Login;
```

This will Work, Try it..

Comment: This will not work when the application closes it will bring the user to the login page again upon next startup

Comment: @DannyLin : isn't that the default, and preferred behaviour of apps like that?

Comment: @Nikunj : please use code formatting.

Comment: oh...ok..next time will not happen..sorry.